# PHP pages that store information between forms so that the form information is stored before submit

Tags: php, forms, registration

This is inside a PHP website form.

An example is like:
First page:
-Username:
-Password

Second page:
-Email
-[Checkbox]

Thirdpage:
-Contact Details
-Address

Fourth page:
Review all of the above forms in hard copy but with a back and forward command so that the user does not loose any information when switching between these pages.

Please post.

Comment: sessions (very handy but dependent on cookies), or store each bit of data you need to store in hidden form fields on every page (painful)

Answer (score 1):

You could use cookies and do your own sessions with MySQL too. I like doing it like that because the data is easier to access if necessary.

Or you can pass the previous variables to the next page though hidden form elements.. but that can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use session. I like Zend_Session.

Comment: You could also use cookies to stash the data until it's done.  Using sessions is the more appropriate route, but you don't *have* to use sessions.

Comment: If you're going to go with cookies, then might as well use sessions. Cookies *DO* have a size limit that's different for each. Careless use of the cookies could lose form data, so just use a session and save yourself the debugging hassle. Unlike that such a simple form would exceed the limit, but you can never be too careful.

Comment: @surreal dreams: would you use cookies to store password?

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be able to come back later and complete the form (assuming you have some kind of login system, or a way to recognize users), you could still save the data into a database.  Make another table, temp_submissions.  Keep data in it until the user completes the form and commits the data they send.  Once committed, clear the data out of the temp_submissions folder and insert it into the "permanent" table.  It may not be practical in this case, or total overkill, but it's an alternative to sessions and cookies.

Comment: Ahh I see, both are good ideas, but i'm wondering how i would store data in sessions?, or would i specify i new session for every peice of information they submit? such as $_SESSION['USERNAME']=$_POST['username'] and whatnot?